# Cannot re-save product programmatically on 2.1.6

Tags: product, magento-2.1, catalog, special-price

I have a simple script which updates product's special price:

```
/** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $repository */
$repository = $this->getObjectManager()->create('\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
$product = $repository->getById(10, true);

$specialPrice = 29;
$from = 1452556800;
$to = 1573516800;
$product->setCustomAttributes([
    'special_price' => $specialPrice,
    'special_from_date' => date('m/d/Y', $from),
    'special_to_date' => date('m/d/Y', $to),
]);

$repository->save($product);
```

It works OK, but since Magento version 2.1.6, it fails with exception: `Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException: Unable to save product`

When I dig deeper to [ProductRepository.php](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ProductRepository.php#L609) I found out that the actual exception is: `InvalidArgumentException: Required parameter 'area' was not passed`.

According [it's stack trace](https://pastebin.com/1ekUcs62) it looks like it has something to do with images.

I tried to comment out the code which sets the custom attributes and just load and save the product with any changes - still the same error.

I run clean installation of Magento 2.1.6 with just [sample data](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/sample-data.html) deployed.

Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks!